# How to break a async function at specific point of time

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, cancellation

Sorry for my bad English!

I have a code structure like this:

```js
var fooResolved;   

int();

setTimeout(() => fooResolved(), 3000); // Just for testing we resolve the foo using a timeout manually

async function int(){

  await foo('usage');
  console.log('foo Resolved'); // if we see this log the foo is resolved

}

// this is my code structure I just put a switch inside the foo function nothing special
async function foo(type){

   switch (type) {
        
       case 'usage':

         mm();

         async function mm() {

           await a();   

           await b();  

           await c();  

           await d();

           fooResolved();

         }

       break;

   }

  return new Promise((resolve) => { 
  fooResolved = resolve;
  });

} // End of foo function


// These are our a and b and c and d function all same as they resolve by a timeout in 2 seconds
function a() {

  console.log('a');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}

function b() {

  console.log('b');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}

function c() {

  console.log('c');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}

function d() {

  console.log('d');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}
```

As you see we resolve the `foo` function while there are two functions (`c` and `d`) not resolved yet.

What if we want to break the `foo` function as we execute the `fooResolved()` so that we don't need to resolve the remaining functions?

I mean we shouldn't see the `c` and `d` logs in the above code ...

> a
>
> b
>
> foo Resolved

if we execute the `fooResolved()` right after `c` we should see this and etc...

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> foo Resolved

Note that in this last example `d` will never be executed.

Answers and comments based on my code structure are greatly appreciated...

Comment: You could set a flag and between the lines add a check `if (cancelled) return`. Or use a library like [interruptible-tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interruptible-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Promise cannot be used to cancel existing async functions in the normal way. As shown below, it is possible to stop execution of async functions that have not yet been executed using the flag.

```js
let fooAborted = false;   

int();

setTimeout(() => fooAborted = true, 3000); // Just for testing we abort the foo using a timeout manually

async function int(){
  try {
    await foo('usage');
  } catch(e) {
    if (e == 'Aborted') {
       console.log('foo aborted'); // if we see this log the foo is aborted
    }
  }

}

// this is my code structure I just put a switch inside the foo function nothing special
async function foo(type){

   switch (type) {
        
       case 'usage':

         await mm();

         async function mm() {
           const jobs = [a, b, c, d]

           for (job of jobs) {
              if (fooAborted) {
                 throw 'Aborted';
              }

              await job();
           }

         }

       break;

   }

} // End of foo function


// These are our a and b and c and d function all same as they resolve by a timeout in 2 seconds
function a() {

  console.log('a');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}

function b() {

  console.log('b');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}

function c() {

  console.log('c');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}

function d() {

  console.log('d');

  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });

}
```